# Use $addFields to add a field from lookup stage without unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to add a field in the aggregation pipeline using $addField stage. In the below query after lookup I dont want to unwind the `provider_info` but want to add a field `p_insensitive` to be used in sort.

```
db.getCollection('providers').aggregate([
{"$lookup": {
    "localField":   "uid",
    "from":         "users",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as":           "provider_info"}},
{"$addFields": {"prov_insensitive": {"$toLower": "$provider_info.full_name"}}},
{"$sort": {"p_insensitive": 1}}

])
```

It is throwing following error:

`can't convert from BSON type array to String`

I can not use unwind stage here according to requirement.

Please help me solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `"$provider_info.full_name"` will return array of `full_name` like `["ABC"]` so `$toLower` operator can only allow string as input,

In this situation you can try one of the option from two,

- [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) starting **from MongoDB v3.2**, returns specific element from specified index,

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "prov_insensitive": {
        "$toLower": {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$provider_info.full_name", 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

- [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/index.html) starting **from MongoDB v4.4**, returns first element from array,

```
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "prov_insensitive": {
        "$toLower": {
          $first: "$provider_info.full_name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```